# How can I force redraw of an *ngIf template in Angular if I don't want the original components / HTML reused

Tags: angular

One great feature of `*ngIf` is you can take an `Observable` and 'observe' it in the template to get a standard object.

As you can see here I'm passing `imageConfig` to my component after subscribing with async pipe.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="model.smartImageConfig$ | async; let imageConfig">

   <app-picture-box [smartImage]="imageConfig"></app-picture-box>

</ng-container>
```

This will reuse the component instance inside, and send in the new data each time it is updated. This is **usually** what we want.

However sometimes you **really need** to recreate the inner template. To be frank this is probably because you have a bug and your component cannot 'refresh' itself properly when it's given a new input parameter. But let's assume that can't be fixed.

An real life reason I need this is for the following example. I have a `@Directive` called `smartImage` that hooks onto the native `picture` tag and creates `source` and `img` elements inside for responsive images.

There's a problem though - if you need to change the configuration of the image you have to delete all the nodes inside and re-add them. Again this is a rare thing you may need to do - but I'm currently working on a 'page editor' which lets you change the source or size of an image.

Unfortunately in Safari (at least in iOS15) there is a bug which means the image is always one update behind. If I change the URL of the image from `cat.jpg` to `dog.jpg` and then to `mouse.jpg` I'll see cat and then nothing and then dog. It literally can't figure out how to refresh itself and gets stuck one step behind. A `setTimeout` to re-set the `img` tag works but is literally an awful solution.

So how can I make an `*ngIf` that just redraws the entire template each time it changes.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="model.smartImageConfig$ | async; let imageConfig">

    <picture [smartImage]="imageConfig"></picture>

</ng-container>
```

In Safari this is always one change behind! And in addition Chrome eagarly (but inconsistently) loads the different variations including the `img.src` when it should be using `source`.

Note: this question is **NOT** anything to do with Change Detection. It's about refreshing the template view as if it were delted and re-added.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is nest an `ngFor` inside the `ngIf` like this.

Note there is an in place array `[imageConfig]` in the declaration of `ngFor`.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="model.smartImageConfig$ | async; let imageConfig; else noConfig">

   <!-- force refresh, by iterating through -->
   <ng-container *ngFor="let config of [imageConfig]">
       <picture [smartImage]="imageConfig"></picture>
   </ng-container>

</ng-container>
```

Internally this uses a `trackByFunction` which works on the identity of the object and so if the identity changes then it gets redrawn.

Final notes:

- It is rare that you should need to do this. Most likely if dealing with a bug in your own code that needs a quick fix, or an external bug you have no control over.
- You could use `*ngFor="let config of [model.smartImageConfig$ | async]"` instead of the nested approach, but then the initial value would be `undefined` (async pipe signature) - so I prefer the double wrapping.
- Make sure the observable is only emitting actual changes that you want to cause the control to refresh. You may need to use `distinctUntilChanged`, `shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true })` etc. to achieve this.
- If it's not clear if the control is being destroyed or not:

1. Look in your browser's element tree and expand out the nodes. You'll be able to see when they're recreated (varies by browser).
2. Put a `<input/>` control inside the `*ngFor` and type into it. When the template is redrawn the text will disappear.

Comment: You probably can simplify like this:
<ng-container *ngIf="model.smartImageConfig$ | async; let imageConfig; else noConfig">
       <picture *ngFor="let config of [imageConfig]" [smartImage]="config"></picture>
</ng-container>

Comment: @AlexanderTrakhimenok thanks - yes that did work! In fact you can even reuse the same variable name `<picture *ngFor="let imageConfig of [imageConfig]" [smartImage]="imageConfig"` like that. Ran into this again today.

Comment: "reusing" of a variable name would not pass my code review. As it's confusing and may cause unexpected issues down the road.